# Convert string Date into timestamp in Android?

Tags: android, timestamp

I want to convert my date (which is in String format), e.g. 13-09-2011, into Timestamp. I used below code but I got the 2011-09-13 00:00:00.0
 as a result. But I want Timestamp like,1312828200000 format.

I cannot understand how to convert that.

My code:

```
String str_date="13-09-2011";
DateFormat formatter ; 
Date date ; 
formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
date = (Date)formatter.parse(str_date); 
java.sql.Timestamp timeStampDate = new Timestamp(date.getTime());
System.out.println("Today is " +timeStampDate);
```

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now legacy, supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android in the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 74, accepted):

If you use `getTime()` of `Date` object you will get time in millisecond.
No need to use `Timestamp` to get your result.

```
String str_date="13-09-2011";
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
Date date = (Date)formatter.parse(str_date); 
System.out.println("Today is " +date.getTime());
```

The above code will print something like `1312828200000` you need and this is long value.

Comment: hi, how can i convert date and time to long "12-09-2011"+"12:30"

Comment: Hi. I have a input as `String dateStr = "26-04-2016 19:45";
        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy kk:mm");` and I tried the solution given by you, but it gives wrong result.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now legacy, supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android in the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Comment: getTime() gets not the time in millisecond! use getTimeInMillis() to get the timestamp as a string

Answer (score 18):

```
String str_date=month+"-"+day+"-"+yr;
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
Date date = (Date)formatter.parse(str_date); 
long output=date.getTime()/1000L;
String str=Long.toString(output);
long timestamp = Long.parseLong(str) * 1000;
```

Comment: ONLY THIS IS CORRECT ANSWER ALL OTHER ANSWER GIVE INCORRECT RESULT

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
"Today is " +timeStampDate
```

calls `TimeStamp.toString()` method "which Formats a timestamp in JDBC timestamp escape format. `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.fffffffff`, where ffffffffff indicates nanoseconds."

The TimeStamp you got internally has the value you want. If you want to get it than use:
`System.out.println("Today is " + timeStampDate.getTime());`

```
    String str_date="13-09-2011";
    DateFormat formatter ; 
    Date date ; 
    formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    date = (Date)formatter.parse(str_date);
    java.sql.Timestamp timeStampDate = new Timestamp(date.getTime());
    System.out.println("Today is " + timeStampDate.getTime());
```

Or if you don't need the `Timestamp`, you can directly use `date.getTime()`. It `"Returns the Date as a millisecond value."`:

```
    String str_date="13-09-2011";
    DateFormat formatter ; 
    Date date ; 
    formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    date = (Date)formatter.parse(str_date);
    System.out.println("Today is " + date.getTime());
```

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

Use modern *java.time* classes.

```
LocalDate.parse( 
    "13-09-2011" , 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd-MM-uuuu" ) 
)
.atStartOfDay(
    ZoneId.of( "Africa/Casablanca" )  // Or use `ZoneOffset.UTC` instead of a zone.
)
.toInstant()
.toEpochMilli()
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/Pf9GKQ).

> 1315872000000

## Details

Apparently you want to represent the first moment of a particular date as a count of milliseconds since the epoch reference of first moment of 1970 in UTC.

## java.time

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes that years ago supplanted the troublesome legacy classes such as `Date`, `Calendar`, and `SimpleDateFormat`.

First parse your input string as a `LocalDate`, for a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

Tip: Rather then using such custom formats when exchanging date-time values as text, use standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats. The *java.time* classes use them by default when parsing/generating strings.

```
String input = "13-09-2011" ;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd-MM-uuuu" ) ;
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( input , f ) ;
```

Determine the first moment of the day on that date. Doing so requires a time zone.  For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

If no time zone is specified, the JVM implicitly applies its current default time zone. That default may [change at any moment](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getDefault()) during runtime(!), so your results may vary. Better to specify your [desired/expected time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) explicitly as an argument.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 2-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
```

Never assume the day starts at 00:00. In some zones on some dates, the day may start at another time such as 01:00. Let *java.time* determine first moment.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ld.startOfDay( z ) ;  // Determine first moment of the day on this date in this zone. May not be 00:00.
```

Adjust to UTC from that zone by extracting a `Instant`.

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;
```

Get a count of milliseconds since 1970-01-01T00:00Z. Beware of possible data loss, as an `Instant` carries a finer resolution of nanoseconds. Any microseconds or nanoseconds will be ignored.

```
long millisecondsSinceEpoch = instant.toEpochMilli() ;
```

You can go back the other direction, from a count-from-epoch to a `Instant`.

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli( millisecondsSinceEpoch) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 1):

**Kotlin**

```
val dateString = "17-09-2021"
val formatter = SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH)
val date = formatter.parse(dateString) as Date
Log.i("i","Today is " + date.time)
```

You'll get something that resembles 1616668471659

Answer (score 0):

It may can help you

```
    long time= System.currentTimeMillis();//timestamp in milliseconds of current time


    String tp = Long.toString(time);//use timestamp as a string
```