# Ormlite orderBy max(ColumnName)

Tags: android, sqlite, ormlite, query-builder

Hi I need to use order by `max(columnName)` in ORMLite.  I have the SQL query but I need to  know how this query is used.  This is my query:

```
SELECT  * FROM table where place = 'somePlace' group by name
    order by MAX (statusDate)
```

`statusDate` column contains date in `"yyyy-dd-mm"` format.  The result I got is the list with recentDates.

Comment: To be sure to understand ? You need to know how to make your sql request with ormlite ?

Comment: @HoodVinci Yes exactly i need the corresponding ormlite query of the above

Comment: What is the difference btw ordering by `statusDate` versus order by its MAX?  I think you should just use `order by` and remove the `MAX` keyword.

Comment: @Gray that is because i got same names with different dates and i need only the recent date .

Answer (score 2):

Use a query builder, and function where and orderBy to preoceed

```
QueryBuilder<YourObject, Integer> q = yourDaoObject.queryBuilder();
Where<YourObject, Integer> wh = q.where();
wh.eq("place", "some_place");
q.orderBy("statusDate", false);
List<YourListOfObects> yourList = q.query();
```

But before that you should store a long instead to store your Date https://stackoverflow.com/a/6993420/2122876

Comment: Thanks for the the answer but i need the max(statusDate) it is for getting the latest name entry.so that the result list will contain only the datas with recent dates

Answer (score 0):

> i got same names with different dates and i need only the recent date.

If you are trying to get element from `Table` with the maximum `statusDate` then you should be doing an descending order-by with a limit of 1.  Something like:

```
QueryBuilder<Foo, Integer> qb = fooDao.queryBuilder();
qb.where().eq("place", "some_place");
qb.orderBy("sttusDate", false); // descending sort
// get the top one result
qb.limit(1);
Foo result = qb.queryForFirst();
```

Comment: but i need all the list from a single query.that is in some names there is only one date and for some there are different dates ,and i need to get all the list(ie if same names with different date choose its max date and if only one name choose its corrresponding date )

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this. Please create your own query builder on the first line.

```
QueryBuilder<MyRowObject, Integer> queryBuiler = "Get Query builder" //getDaoXXX().queryBuilder();

MyRowObject firstLatestRow = queryBuiler.orderBy("dateColoumn", false).queryForFirst();
```

Hope this helps