# Timestamp from String in android

Tags: android, timestamp

I have a problem with timestamp. I get String: `2014-09-20 18:49:48.773829+00:00` and I need to get Timestamp from this string. When I use `Timestamp.valueof(String)` I get:

```
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Timestamp format must be yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fffffffff; was '2014-09-20 18:49:48.773829+00:00'
            at java.sql.Timestamp.badTimestampString(Timestamp.java:507)
            at java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf(Timestamp.java:467)
            at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest.deliverResponse(JsonRequest.java:65)
            at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

How can I get timestamp from my string?

Comment: You could format your string to fit that format? SimpleDateFormat or somethin?

Comment: see this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6993365/convert-string-date-into-timestamp-in-android

Hope it helps,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is probably in the first string - `Timestamp format must be yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fffffffff.` Otherwise you'll get parsing exception.

Comment: nanoseconds - see [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/sql/Timestamp.html#valueOf(java.lang.String))