# Unable to convert string "7:05 AM" to time

Tags: android

i am trying to convert "7:05AM" into timestamp but it's not working.

```
 try {
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a");
            Date parsedDate = dateFormat.parse("7:05AM");
            Timestamp timestamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(parsedDate.getTime());
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

        }
```

Comment: how do you figure that your date matches your format?

Comment: have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6993365/convert-string-date-into-timestamp-in-android

Answer (score 0):

Change SimpleDateFormat ("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a") to ("hh:mm a") its working fine

```
 try {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
        Date parsedDate = dateFormat.parse("7:05 AM");
        Timestamp timestamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(parsedDate.getTime());
        System.out.println(timestamp.toString());
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
```

Comment: it's not working.  giving the exception Unparseable date "7 :05 AM"

Comment: This will work, it will give you an output like this 1970-01-01 07:05:00.0 You class file should contain the following import statements `import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;`